# How to export DLLs that have dependency on other DLLs?

Tags: c++, dll

Say I have an EXE main program that searches for DLLs in a folder "plugins\" and its subfolders, and then list the Plugin names of all available DLLs. The folder structure looks like below.

```
EXE
  |
  |--plugins\
       |
       |--A\   --> A.dll
       |--A-1\ --> A-1.dll
       |--B\   --> B.dll
```

Each DLL export a Plugin class like below

```
// A.DLL
class __declspec(dllexport) A : PluginBase
{
public:
    void virtual Func( void );
};

// A-1.DLL
class __declspec(dllexport) A_1 : public A
{
public:
    void virtual Func( void );
};

// B.DLL
class __declspec(dllexport) B: public PluginBase
{
public:
    void virtual Func( void );
}
```

All three DLLs are located in different folders. In some situations, it is not desirable that folder "A\" and A.dll is shown for users, but only folder "A-1\" and A-1.dll is shown. However, when A-1.dll is loaded by LoadLibrary(), A.dll must exist and searchable, when A-1.dll is dynamically linked with A.dll.

I don't want to load all DLLs searched all the time. Instead, I want to load A.DLL when users select Plugin A, B.DLL when users select Plugin B, and A-1.DLL when users select Plugin A-1. A-1.DLL has dependency on A.DLL, however.

I wonder if it is suggested class A is statically linked into A-1.dll rather than dynamically for my situation?

Comment: Why can't you just link `A.dll` dynamically to `A-1.dll`? Then it will be loaded when user selects `A-1.dll`. If you link statically then if you decide to update `A.dll` you'll have to update `A-1.dll` as well, while with dynamic linking `A-1.dll` would automatically load the updated version.

Comment: Hi Rudolfs. You means that when A-1.dll is dynamically linked with A.dll, it will also automatically loads A.dll when EXE main progroam loads A-1.dll with LoadLibrary() calls?

Comment: yes `LoadLibrary` loads all the dependencies (however check MSDN regarding the search paths, otherwise they will not be found) of the module it is loading.

Comment: Hi Ruldolfs and Story, I edited my original post to describe my situation more clearly. Thanks for your kindly reply.

Comment: You seem to be using implicit dynamic linking. Then how would `LoadLibrary` be useful?

Comment: If you want to use explicit dynamic linking, consider using variants of COM.

Comment: Hi Lingxi. The EXE main program or the plugin manager uses explicit dynamic linking LoadLibrary() to load either A.dll, A-1.dll, or B.dll. But in some situation it is desirable that only A-1.dll is searched without its dependent A.dll.

Answer (score 0):

use AddDllDirectory API to add new search directory the the PATH;
check API declaration from MSDN
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh310513%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Hi milevyo. Thanks for your kindly reply. My platform in under Windows 8, so I use SetDllDirectory() instead. According to your suggestion, I put "A.DLL" in other folder out of "plugins\" and add this folder to search path by SetDllDirectory(). This works when only "plugins\A-1\A-1.DLL" exists in plugin folder.